# Parametrized Oracle Command with slow performance

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, ado.net

We have a .Net application running with Oracle using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` v12.1.24160719 provider. It works fine for the most of queries on the system, but, a specifique query is kind of slow.

For sample, when the query is executed on the `OracleCommand` without any `OracleParameter` or with parameters directly on the query (string harded coded), it executes fine and fast. If we hit the same query on the PL/SQL Oracle editor, it also executes fine and fast. It take less then 2 seconds.

However, when we pass the oracle parameters for the arguments, it take a slow performance, something like 15 seconds. We have 22 parameters on the query. If we active the property `BbindByName` of the `OracleCommand` there is no result on it.

It is a generic code that uses DbProviderFactory to execute customer queries to extract data from his database. The code works but it is slow then the `ExecuteReader` is executed.

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");

using (var con = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString.Value;
    con.Open();

    using (var command = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Connection = con;

        // the parameters collection comes from outside of this scope
        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            var param = command.CreateParameter();

            param.ParameterName = p.Name;

            // because this method is just a test, we do not have values,
            // so, we pass DBNull.Value to arguments because it should just test the query sintaxe and check if it works.
            param.Value = DBNull.Value;

            command.Parameters.Add(param);
        }       

        // on ExecuteReader we get the slow performance
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            // hydrated some data structure here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to know what can be the performance issue of this problem?

Comment: You should post your code to be helped.

Comment: Maybe `bind variable peeking`

Comment: Without code to reproduce it, we can not really help you. However 22 paramters is an awfull lot for any query. Short of a Insert or you trying to do calculation work on the DB side, those counts should be impossible. It is also quite possible that Paramtetized queries have a "tipping point" beyond wich string conaction build is preferable. Because again, 22 Paramters is a lot of variables.

Comment: It could be that you bind a string value to a parameter of another type (int date etc) and Rdbms use a function to convert this value to a proper type preventing at the some time from using an index on this column. But it is only one possibility, without looking at your code and at the plan it is guessing game. I vote to close your question.

Comment: I believe @krokodilko is correct: you have a type mismatch. I have seen this many times where Oracle will convert the column to match the parameter data type and you get terrible performance. Make certain that all of your parameters are of the same data type as the column against which you are matching.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code, I will try to execute with a less number of parameters to check the performance.

Comment: You can print a type for each `param.Value = p.Value;`, then compare with a type of corresponding column in your query (hint: `DESC table` list all columns together with their tppes). If you find that some parameter has different type than column's type, you can use an explicit cast in the query. You can also [enable tracing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL791) for the query and analyze bind parameters in the trace file, this can give some clue.

Comment: I think it is that the cached plan might be inappropriate. Perhaps due skewed data. I suggest that you test to execute with hardcoded parameters also from C#.

Comment: @user2672165 as I comment on the question, when execute from C# without parameters (I mean, the string sql with the arguments on hard code) there is not performance issue.

Comment: Ok. Then one option could be to compare the two different plans you get. You could possibly guide the optimizer to the beneficial plan using a hint.

Comment: I also suspect what @krokodilko pointed out to. Usually, if you have a varchar2 and compare it to a number the index is not used (and not visa versa)

Comment: Guys, sorry, the value we are passing for each parameter is `DbNull.Value` because it is a method to test the query and when we have arguments, it pass null value just to test the query. Maybe it is the reason we have slow performance. How could I solve it if we do not know the column type to provide a typed value? This method should just run the query and check if it is working.